# cURL or xargs: show progress

Tags: bash, curl, command-line, wget, xargs

I am using cURL to download many files and concatenate them to STDOUT. About 100,000 small files. I would like to see progress against the 100,000. Is this possible with curl or by using curl into xargs?

Interested in only standard command line solutions.

Comment: it is possible to display something like: "downloading [200/100000]". but as you said, you want to print the file contents to stdout. if you got status/progress information, they should be printed to stdout as well. it will mess your stdout up. what do you exactly want?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different things you could do here: but without knowing exactly your curl methodology I can just offer a few suggestions.

**Make an iterative counting for loop:**

`for file {1..100000}; do echo "downloading: $file" >&2 ; curl [whatever] ; done`
This will redirect the "downloading: $file"to STDERR so if you're using a redirect on STDOUT it won't mess it it up but you can still see it on the screen

`for file {1..100000}; do echo "downloading: $file" >> progress.out ; curl [whatever] ; done`
This writes progress to a file so it won't show up on the screen at all, then you can just tail -f progress.out

**If your curl isn't iterative:**

terminal 1:
`curl [whatever] | tee progress.out`

terminal 2:
`watch -n5 "grep -c '[unique file delimiter]' progress.out"`

tee writes a copy of STDOUT to a file, and you grep count for something that only appears once per HTML doc... maybe a `<HEAD>` or `<HTML>` tag or something else.  Watch will just run the grep it every 5 seconds to let you know how many you have completed.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Parallel is more or less standard these days:

```
cat urls | parallel -j30 --eta curl ... > out
```

Added benefit: multiple curls will be run in parallel.

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1